# Adobe Illustrator save png image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png

I have created 9 images with 2500x1500 resolution using illustrator and saved it as png  for my game, it shows 10-20kb each of them but while the game is running they are 100mb in ram , I know that png of 10-20kb is compressed png but 100mb for 9 images is really big so how can I make that png images smaller (file size of uncompressed image) without loosing quality .And which is the best way to save the image for mobile game ?

Comment: Uncompressed, your images are going to be 1,500 x 2,500 **x** the number of bytes per pixel *each*. If you are thinking of bringing this uncompressed size down, you need to rethink why they are so large to begin with. No amount of manipulation will make the uncompressed images themself smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I would open them in Photoshop and use the Save For Web dialog box (File > Save For Web).

[image: menu]

Adjust the settings and try reducing the # of colors, until you find a good balance between file size and quality.

[image: size]

Use the 2-Up view to compare the original vs. compressed file.

[image: 2-up]